# Should I say flip, switch or flick the switch?

Tags: word-choice

Suppose I have a switch with two positions, something like an interruptor, and two light bulbs. Switch on position A turns on the first light bulb, changing it to position B, turns on the second light bulb.

Which should I say?

- I have flipped the switch from A to B
- I have flicked the switch from A to B
- I have switched the switch from A to B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**flip versus flick**  [wikidiff](https://wikidiff.com/flip/flick)

> As nouns the difference between flip and flick is that flip is a
>   maneuver which rotates an object end over end or flip can be a mixture
>   of beer, spirit, etc, stirred and heated by a hot iron (a flip dog )
>   while flick is a short, quick movement, especially a brush, sweep, or
>   flip. As verbs the difference between flip and flick is that flip is
>   to throw (as in to turn over) while **flick is to move or hit
>   (something) with a short, quick motion**.

My sense would be to **flick a switch**. **Flip a switch** would be second.  I would avoid switch x two in a sentence.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Amazing knowledge. Wikidiff? Never heard about that before. Nice to know. Cannot upvote you enough!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: This may be a regional thing...  Living my entire life on the west coast of the US, I would never think to use "flick" in this context; switches are flipped.  This is true also, btw, in computing.  Bits and switches are flipped.

Comment: [The `FL-` assonance](https://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/fl.pdf) has several words that work here. And the [`-ip` rime](https://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/-ip.pdf) is quite coherent; it basically means anything -- especially small things -- that's slightly off the level -- concave or convex -- like a switch. or a button.

Answer (score 2):

The first 2 are completely valid

> I have flipped the switch from A to B
>
> I have flicked the switch from A to B

but

> I have switched the switch from A to B

wouldn't be said just say it out loud and you will find out why.
You would instead say

**I have switched the telly off**

or

**I have switched the heating to high**

---

Source native British English speaker

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, "flipped" is the most normal of the first two. However, "flicked" is fine if you're wanting to add a sense of speed and/or carelessness to the movement.

In the last example, you could simply say "I switched it from A to B," and that would get rid of any redundancy.